# init DynamicLinks is not runnig navigator function

Tags: flutter, navigation, firebase-dynamic-links

I have firebase dynamic link in my app, it is creating a deep link for me and when click on it outside of app it is opening my app, and init dynamic link is run as well, and there I get `itemId` from dynamic link, check it to not be null, when it wasn't null it will print it to console, and debug printer is work as well, but I have there a `Navigator.push` function, my problem is here, every thing is work as well except that `Navigator`.
what should I do?

**here is my dynamic link class**

```dart
class DynamicLinkProvider {
  Future<String> createLink(String itemId) async {
    final String url = 'https://co.lajward.tubre?itemId=$itemId';

    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
        androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
            packageName: 'co.lajward.tubre', minimumVersion: 0),
        iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
            bundleId: 'co.lajward.tubre', minimumVersion: '0'),
        link: Uri.parse(url),
        uriPrefix: 'https://tubre.page.link');
    final FirebaseDynamicLinks link = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;
    final refLink = await link.buildShortLink(parameters);
    return refLink.shortUrl.toString();
  }

  Future<void> initDynamicLinks(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) async {
        String? itemId = dynamicLinkData.link.queryParameters['itemId'];
        Future<bool> documentExists(
            String collectionName, String documentId) async {
          try {
            final DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection(collectionName)
                .doc(documentId);
            final DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
            return docSnapshot.exists;
          } catch (e) {
            debugPrint('documentExists error is: $e');
            return false;
          }
        }

        if (itemId != null) {
          bool validId = await documentExists('items', itemId);
          debugPrint('validId is: $validId');
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
                itemId: itemId,
                finalReference: null,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      });

      final PendingDynamicLinkData? data =
          await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
      String? itemId = data?.link.queryParameters['itemId'];
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('items')
          .doc(itemId)
          .get()
          .then((snapshot) {
        debugPrint('items is: ${snapshot.data()}');
        // StoryData storyData = StoryData.fromSnapshot(snapshot);

        // return Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
        //     StoryPage(story: storyData,)
        // ));
      });
      if (itemId != null) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
              itemId: itemId,
              finalReference: null,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return debugPrint('');
    }
  }
}
```

and here I call it in main.dart, at home class

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    DynamicLinkProvider().initDynamicLinks(context);
    super.initState();
  }
```